# Format img width dynamically based on initial onload width in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, reactjs

I want to format an `img`'s width or height dynamically based on its initial width or height onload inside a React component but both of the below doesn't work, with the first not rendering the `img` at all and the 2nd not being able to find the `some-img`. Is what I'm wanting to do possible?

```
  const img = new Image()
  img.onload = () => {
    const height = img.height
    const width = img.width

    if (width < height) {
      img.style.width = '105px'
    } else {
      img.style.height = '105px'
    }
  }
  img.src = avatar.url

  render () {
    return (
      img
    )
  }
```

OR

```
  const formatImg = () => {
    const height = img.height
    const width = img.width

    if (width < height) {
      document.getElementById('some-img').style.width = '105px'
    } else {
      document.getElementById('some-img').style.height = '105px'
    }

  }

  render () {
    return (
      <img src={avatar.url} onload={formatImg()} id="some-img" />
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some misunderstanding about `new Image` and `onload`.

The first code, what to be rendered should be an "HTML Element"(at least looks like), but `img = new Image` is not. So what you do with variable `img` of course not works.

The second code, `onload = {formatImg()}` means return value of formatImg() assigned to onload prop. You should code like this: `onload = {formatImg}`.

And the last thing, if I am using React, I would never try to manipulate DOM elements directly. Instead, as possible to use `setState` so that `render` cycle runs.

Modify your second a bit like this:

```
const formatImg = () => {
  const height = img.height
  const width = img.width

  if (width < height) {
    this.setState({width: '105px', height: height + 'px'})
   // document.getElementById('some-img').style.width = '105px'
  } else {
    this.setState({width: width + 'px', height: '105px'})
   // document.getElementById('some-img').style.height = '105px'
  }
}

render () {
  const { width, height } = this.state;
  return (
    <img src={avatar.url} onload={this.formatImg} style={{width, height} />
  )
}
```

Comment: Be careful, when you're using tags like <img> in React, you are not using html. It's JSX

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but doing just `onload={formatImg}` without the `()` doesn't call it at all

Comment: I've edit my answer, `this.formatImg` should be used since it's an instance method of the component.

Answer (score -1):

The first is not working because the render() method is not supposed to return DOM elements. I think you misunderstand how React is supposed to work. 
 The tags that you use in React are not html, nor are they html DOM elements. The tags are JSX, which is syntactical sugar that is understood by Babel, and turned into regular javascript when it generates the bundle javascript file. 

 So the following JSX:

```
<h1>hello</h1>
```

Gets turned into the following javascript:

```
React.createElement(
  "h1",
  null,
  "hello"
);
```

This is why you have to use

```
import React from 'react';
```

even when it doesn't look like you're using it anywhere.
 In reality, you actually **are** using it, because that's what the JSX stands for.

Anyways, going back to the above code, the first argument "h1" for createElement tells React that you want the type to be "h1", and the the third argument is "hello" because that's what you want the child to be.

So if your JSX is :

```
<div><img></img></div>
```

Then the compiled javascript is:

```
React.createElement(
  "div",
  null,
  React.createElement("img", null)
);
```

If you want to play around with JSX, you can use this:
https://babeljs.io/repl/

Now the important part. When you're using React.createElement, you are **not** creating the DOM element. You're not even instantiating the React component (if you defined your own component).

All you're doing is giving React a template structure that tells React what you **intend** to do. And React will handle the actual "doing" when it sees fit, and the way it sees fit.

That template structure I talked about, for example:

```
React.createElement(
  "h1",
  null,
  "hello"
);
```

is special. 
 The return() method of any React component **must** return that type of object. It cannot return anything else, and it definitely cannot return a DOM object.

Your second code block will *almost* work, although it's still not the preferred way of doing something like this in React. But if you really want to do it that way, there are some things you need to fix.

First, the "onload" property should be spelled "onLoad". Also, you need to use

```
this.formatImage
```

Make sure you don't use the brackets, or else the code will actually run before React even puts your image on the page. Now why does it do this? 
Because Babel will transform your JSX:

```
<img onload={formatImg()} id="some-img" />
```

into this:

```
React.createElement(
     "img", 
     { onload: formatImg(), id: "some-img" }
);
```

Notice how in your code, the "formatImg" function actually runs **before** it's even passed into React.createElement as an argument. (Before the template is even created, and definitely before it's put onto the page.)